# Write loop values to csv file

Tags: python, csv, abaqus

I am working with Abaqus-python and I would like to write a lot of data to a csv file.
I want to fill multiple columns with my loops. However I don't manage to write loops to my csv file, only the first row. This is my code;

```
import csv

# Define list with with partnames
PartNames = ["C7", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7", "T8", "T9", "T10", "T11", "T12",
             "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "S1"]

# Create lists to save data
PartLevelLeft, aLabels, axcoords, aycoords, azcoords  = [], [], [], [], []

for i in range(len(PartNames)-1):  # S1 does not contain screws
    PartLevelLeft = mdb.models[modelname].rootAssembly.sets["Screw['" + PartNames[i] + "_L']"]

    for curNode in PartLevelLeft.nodes:
        partlabelL.append(curNode.label)
        partxcordL.append(curNode.coordinates[0])
        partycordL.append(curNode.coordinates[1])
        partzcordL.append(curNode.coordinates[2])

    aLabels.append(partlabelL)
    axcoords.append(partxcordL)
    aycoords.append(partycordL)
    azcoords.append(partzcordL)

    # Arrays with multiple coordinates of different nodes
    pt1L = [axcoords[0][0], aycoords[0][0], azcoords[0][0]]
    print('pt1L = ', pt1L, 'pt1PartlabelL = ', pt1PartlabelL, 'pt1InstanceName = ', "Screw['" + PartNames[i] + "_L']")
```

This prints arrays with different values, I show three printed rows for example;

```
('pt1L = ', [31.1655006408691, -118.636100769043, -846.924499511719], 'pt1PartlabelL = ', 904, 'pt1InstanceName = ', "Screw['L5_L']")
('pt1L = ', [41.5686988830566, -137.057601928711, -815.5546875], 'pt1PartlabelL = ', 1561, 'pt1InstanceName = ', "Screw['L4_L']")
('pt1L = ', [46.5876007080078, -138.033294677734, -776.843994140625], 'pt1PartlabelL = ', 3583, 'pt1InstanceName = ', "Screw['L3_L']")
```

But now I want to write this data into a CSV file using the following code;

```
header = ['pt1PartlabelL', 'pt1L_x ', 'pt1L_y ', 'pt1L_z ']
data = ["Screw['" + PartNames[i] + "_L']", pt1L[0], pt1L[1], pt1L[2]]

# open the file in the write mode
with open(r'C:\1. Abaqus tijdelijk\211214 find displacement\NIEUW ALLES\220112 write to excel.csv', 'wb') as f:
    # create the csv writer
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write a row to the csv file
    writer.writerow(header)
    for row in data:
        # write a row to the csv file
        writer.writerow(data)
```

It only prints the first array of pt1L multiple times, like this;
[image: Output in CSV file]

Can someone help me with the code to have my loops in the CSV file?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `i` set to? `data` is not a list of lists, just a single list.

Comment: To the partnames, so pt1PartLabel etc. I copied 'row' from another topic that included loops and just looked if it did something. I recall that other topic didn't define 'row' either

Comment: It seems that `i` is a counter to iterate over the dataset. Can you give code where this set is created?

Comment: I added some more code to make it a bit clearer (hopefully). "PartNames" are the names of my parts and these parts contain each a nodeset based on the name of that part, e.g.: Screw["C7_L"]. And what I would like to print are the first three initial nodes of the nodesets within all my parts. Let me know if anything is still unclear. I appreciate your help!